# why is wood in crawlspace rotting?

Tags: moisture

Here in the hot and humid south, it is not uncommon for the crawlspace of a house to get so humid that the joists start to suffer from fungal rot.  (More and more people are encapsulating their crawlspace, to avoid this). I am seeking to determine what moisture level is acceptable in a crawlspace.   Anecdotally, knowledgeable people seem to say anything above 50 or 60% is too much.   That doesn't jibe with some data I've found.

This chart (from https://www.woodworkerssource.com/wood-moisture-content.html) shows the moisture content that wood will achieve when in equilibrium with air of a given temperature and RH%:

[image]

Researching various sites discussing wood rot, it seems that anything below 20% will prevent fungal rot; some sources say more like 30%.

Looking at the table, it appears that anything over 25% is impossible (without submerging the wood in water) and that even 20% is un-achievable in the conditions one sees in a poorly-conditioned crawlspace (e.g. 70 degrees with 85% humidity yields 18% moisture content).

So what gives ?   Why is it common to have rotting wood in an un-encapsulated crawlspace in the southern US, when the data suggests this should not be happening.

Comment: Have you measured the humidity in the crawlspace? If not begin tracking it.  In addition track the temperature in the space several times (morning afternoon & night) a day for a while.  If the humidity is high enough the moisture may condense when the temperature drops at night leaving moisture on the wood.  Over time this can create a mold problem and lead to rotting as well.

Comment: hi, I think the chart assumes full kiln drying. Much construction wood is not dried well! Wood used there should be pressure treated anyway so rot is nearly impossible.

Comment: Modern SPF is going to be a factor here, but from my understanding the main issues are the sustained high**er** humidity in the enclosed space, providing a stable environment for whichever fungal species is prevalent (there's more than one) to get a foothold. And of course the other one is that the wood isn't treated. The entire picture changes if the wood used is PT lumber.

Comment: Also this isn't reflective of what a crawlspace can actually be like, *"(e.g. 70 degrees with 85% humidity yields 18% moisture content)."* That's a little like expecting an uninsulated attic in direct sun to be about the same conditions as standing on the lawn in the shadow of the house :-) In a lot of the hot & humid south I'd imagine temps regularly exceed 70 in the warmest parts of the year, easily the further south you go, and then on top of that it would not be difficult for the RH *in the crawlspace* to be nearly 100% some or all of the time. So that potentially yields EMCs of above 20%.

Comment: Can't measure my humidity now, as I got it encapsulated and it's well under control now.  I was just advising friend, who got his encapsulated, and they said "you don't need a dehumidifier" and he's seeing 60+% RH, and was wondering if that's too high.  Based on the chart, it looks like even 70% is ok.   Which got me to wondering.

Comment: This is best researched over on DIY.SE.

Comment: Ok, thanks all.   I don't think the temperatures in the crawlspace much exceed 70 even though it's often pushing 100 outside.   But perhaps, even at that temperature, RH% values DO get high enough for EMC above 20% ... and that's my answer.

Comment: Still seems like the chart is telling us that 80% crawlspace RH is acceptable - since EMC cannot go above 20% at any temperature.   This flies in the face of conventional wisdom among local builders.

Comment: *"since EMC cannot go above 20% at any temperature"* Rusty, this chart is, I'm fairly certain, assuming properly kiln-dried wood, which construction lumber is not. If it is assuming common or normal starting EMCs for the US (usually single-digit, peaking at *maybe* 11-13% in some places) it's going to be way off base for wood that starts out at something well into the double digits.... anyway put aside all the theorising and just look at what you know: wood does rot in crawlspaces, yes? Ergo *by definition* the EMC of the wood there *can* go above 20%.

Comment: Doesn't "equilibrium" (in "EMC") mean it's going to get to the same place regardless of how it started out ?

Comment: Would it be more accurate to be thinking about the moisture on the surface of the wood? After all, that's where all the growth starts.

Comment: I wonder how all of those 100+ year old homes made it most had no vapor barriers or encapsulated crawl spaces. Just saying a simple vapor barrier is all that is normally needed.

Comment: No A/C, so floor not chilly ?   My A/C'd brick-floor house used to literally RAIN in there before I encapsulatd it.